# MahApps.Metro UI WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps.Metro UI to WPF.
I have problem that my application isn't running on 32bit machine only on 64bit.
I'm tried to change on `Build->x86` but its not solved
Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the symptom? like error message?

Comment: @kennyzx, thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,
I worked with .NET Framework 4.5 that not support on Windows XP according https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx
So i compiled my project with .Net Framework 4.0 with MahApps.Metro .Net 4.0 dlls and the problem is solved